# TabBar inside a ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tabbar

I have a list view with multiple widgets. One of them is the Tabbar. But if I use a tabbar inside a listview, it gives me a render error.

Source Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

import '../../utils/custom_style.dart';

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Settings"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          const Text("Hello"),
          Container(
            width: 100.w,
            height: 50.h,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("01" * 1000),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w),
              child: DefaultTabController(
                length: 3, // length of tabs
                initialIndex: 0,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 65,
                      child: TabBar(
                        labelColor: Colors.black,
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.red,
                        indicatorColor: Colors.green,
                        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                        labelStyle: CustomStyle.textStyle,
                        tabs: const [
                          Text("Episodes"),
                          Text("More Like This"),
                          Text("Trailers and More"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
           
                    const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    Flexible(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        children: [
                          Text("Episodes" * 2000),
                          Text("More Like This" * 3000),
                          Text("Trailers and More"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#b8ed3 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

The Layout I want to achieve:

[image]

If I use fixed height in Sizedbox instead of Expanded as Tabbar's parent widget, it gives no error. but I don't want a fixed height. How Can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want a fixed height for the tabbar, then both the listview and the tabbar can expand indefinitely vertically. Can you describe the UI layout that you visioned?

Comment: Could you please add the design that you want to achieve? I believe tab bar won't be required inside listview. There could be alternative way.

Comment: Wait I'm adding the layout

Comment: post updated. Layout added.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `Listview` in a `Column` and take `Expanded` Widget outside from `Listview`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import '../../utils/custom_style.dart';

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Settings"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              const Text("Hello"),
              Container(
                width: 100.w,
                height: 50.h,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text("01" * 100),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w),
              child: DefaultTabController(
                length: 3, // length of tabs
                initialIndex: 0,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 65,
                      child: TabBar(
                        labelColor: Colors.black,
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.red,
                        indicatorColor: Colors.green,
                        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                        labelStyle: CustomStyle.textStyle,
                        tabs: const [
                          Text("Episodes"),
                          Text("More Like This"),
                          Text("Trailers and More"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    Flexible(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        children: [
                          SingleChildScrollView(child: Text("Episodes" * 2000)),
                          SingleChildScrollView(child: Text("More Like This" * 3000)),
                          SingleChildScrollView(child: Text("Trailers and More")),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, brother. But I forgot to mention one thing, I want to scroll the full screen, not only the Tabbar. How can I achieve this?